# How can I change SparkContext.sparkUser() setting (in pyspark)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new with `Spark` and `pyspark`.
I use pyspark, after my `rdd` processing, I tried to save it to `hdfs` using the `saveAsTextfile()` function. 
But I get a '**permission denied**' error message because pyspark tries to write `hdfs` 
using my local account, 'kjlee', which does not exist on the `hdfs` system.

I can check the spark user name by `SparkContext().sparkUser()`, But I can't find how to change the spark user name.

How can I change the spark user name?

Comment: formatting and proper english.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an environment variable for this : `HADOOP_USER_NAME`
so simply use `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=anyuser` or in pyspark you can use `os.environ["HADOOP_USER_NAME"] = "anyuser"`

Comment: I notice that sometimes you'll need to set this in bash via export `HADOOP_USER_NAME=anyuser` .

Answer (score 5):

In Scala could be done with System.setProperty:

```
  System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME","newUserName")

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("SparkSessionApp")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  println(spark.sparkContext.sparkUser)
```